# script running before html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the page to load before the script runs. I thought that the script tags going at the bottom of the body would achieve this, however, the alert still pops up first. If anyone knows why please help.

```html
 
<body>
  <h1>Website!</h1>
  <p> should load before script</p>
    
  <script>alert("hi")</script>
</body>
```

edit... I have tried the recommended solutions but got the same results as shown here [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j5yO.jpg)
does the alert function just always run first or am I being stupid? Also if it's not clear I am trying to have the contents of the website shown before the alert happens.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno "_I am trying to get the page to load before the script runs_" ie. "_I want the alert to display after the content is showed to the user_" **is** the desired behavior

Comment: I don't see what he tried to do, it's clear that he didn't try to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

When browser starts loading the HTML and it encounter a `<script>` it can't continue to build the DOM. It executes the *script* first and if the *script* has `src` it will wait pause building the DOM for external script to load and execute.

Thus you get `alert()` first then HTML is rendered. You can use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event to wait for DOM to be ready then fire `alert()`

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alert("hi")
    });
 </script>
```

Note: `async` and `defer` attribute with `script` doesn't pause's DOM building  and external scripts are loaded in background

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
<body>
  <h1>Website!</h1>
  <p> should load before script</p>
    
  <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            alert("hi")
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `alert("hi")` with this:

```
window.onload = () => {
  alert("hi");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following to do a function after the window loads:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Website!</h1>
  <p> should load before script</p>
    
  <script>
  window.onload = function(){alert("hi")};
  </script>
</body>
```